# Drawing trees in Common Lisp

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

This question probably has an embarrassingly simple answer, but is there a Right Way to format/draw trees in Common Lisp?  I've tried a few books as well as googling about, but the problem seems to fall between the cracks of the search terms.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What kind of trees do you want to draw?

[SDRAW](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Lisp/sdraw/) draws cons cell structures to a terminal. Similar: [Draw Cons Tree](https://github.com/cbaggers/draw-cons-tree).

If you have [McCLIM](http://common-lisp.net/project/mcclim/), CLIM or a Lisp Machine, you can call the CLIM function [CLIM:FORMAT-GRAPH-FROM-ROOT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLIM/html/climuser-283.htm) or CLIM:FORMAT-GRAPH-FROM-ROOTS.

If you use LispWorks, there is a [graph pane](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CAPRM/html/capiref-148.htm#pgfId-895252).

If you want to draw plants use this one: [L-Lisp](http://www.ii.uib.no/~knute/lsystems/llisp.html).

[image: plant drawing]

Comment: Awesome, SDRAW was exactly what I was looking for: a clean way to represent nested cons cells.  Thanks again.

Comment: WHAT - AN - AWESOME - ANSWER. Wow. You didn't answer just OP but an entire stream of google searchers.

Comment: Another option is (ql:quickload :draw-cons-tree)

Answer (score 5):

If you do decide to go with GraphViz, check out http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-graphviz

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find a better solution, I'd be inclined to emit a .dot file and then feed it to one of the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) tools (like dot). The file format is really simple, and the tools can generate a variety of formats including PNG, SVG, PostScript and even image maps (for creating clickable graphs on web pages).

This approach probably only works for you if you want these graphs for your own use (eg: debugging) or you're generating them on a server. Calling out to a separate tool in a client app might have usability and/or licensing issues.

This isn't really a common-lisp specific solution, but I've used this approach from a few languages in the past.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply.  I was hoping to print straight to the console, but your suggestion sounds much more flexible for large trees.  Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I have used [lisp2dot](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/W.Langdon/lisp2dot) (an Awk script that generates Dot commands) in recent years in GP applications but currently it does not seem to work. Every time i feed it with valid Lisp expression it returns strange  Dot files with full of nonsense error messages. Nevertheless, it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I had an opportunity to check back [lisp2dot](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/W.Langdon/lisp2dot) and it still seems to be working but beware of the function names and arity of function nodes which can be tricky in Awk.